# How to get file data from input html element

Tags: html, file, jscript

I'm trying to do a quick client side file check for UX in jscript, but I'm getting an error that I don't know how to fix. I'm getting a file through an input:

I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

Every time I searched for how to do this, it gives me the solution I've implemented. When I log file, it returns the file path so maybe that's the issue, that it cannot get the size from the file path alone?

I tried using an approach based on events but I was getting the same error.

```js
const MAXSIZEMB = 100000;

function checkSize() {
  const file = document.getElementById("file").value;
  console.log(file);
  const max = MAXSIZEMB * 1024 * 1024;
  if (file.files[0].size > max) {
    alert("Files size cannot exceed " + MAXSIZEMB + " MB");
    file = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="checkSize()" />
```

Comment: You certainly cannot reset `file = "";` which is a const

Comment: @mplungjan Yea true, I hadn't reached that far because the error was earlier. `document.getElementById("file").value = "";` should work right?

Comment: "it cannot get the size from the file path alone" — Well, no. That's just a string. Strings aren't files.

Comment: @Quentin Poor dupe. OP wants the size and not read the file on the client

Answer (score 0):

You need the file, not file.value

You cannot set the value of a file input for obvious security reasons

You CAN wrap the file input in a form and reset the form

```js
const MAXSIZEMB = 100;
const max = MAXSIZEMB * 1024 * 1024;

function checkSize() {
  const file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
  console.log(file.size)
  if (file.size > max) {
    alert("Files size cannot exceed " + MAXSIZEMB + " MB");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="checkSize()" />
```

Comment: Right, thanks. Should have been obvious...